# One module field use to other module in openerp

Tags: odoo

I created a field name "link to opportunities" :-
module :- hr.applicant
field type:- many2many
object relation:- crm.lead

and i used in crm.lead module .

Now i want to use this field in "hr.recruitment" .
but i have tried many ways but not success. please tell me. how can use this field in other module like as crm.lead to hr.recruitment

thank you for your timing.

this code i used:-

```
   'sale_o_ids' : fields.related('job_id', 'x_link_to_jobposition',
                                   readonly=True,
                                   relation='crm.lead',
                                   string='Opportunity Name'),
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: You add this field in hr.applicant, and same field want to used in hr.recruitment, or same new field want to add in hr.recruitment?

Comment: thank u . I want add this field in hr.applicant and same this field want to used in hr.recruitment. so whenever this field will update in hr.applicant then i can see this value in hr.recruitment.This field will create only one. but used in two other module . thank you please suggest me

Comment: Plz Check . I am wait for your kindly response.

Comment: you can make the function field in hr.recruitment of field hr.applicant field. You can find many example in addons of openerp

Comment: thnx but i will try. but may you create one ? i am new in openerp

Comment: Wait I will create an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

of many2many

```
class hr_job(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'hr.job'
    _columns = {
        'sale_ids': fields.many2many('sale.order', 'hr_job_sale_order_rel', 'job_id', 'sale_id', 'Sale order'),
    }

hr_job()
```

Here created a many2many field of sale.order

Now i want to used the hr.job field in hr.employee.

```
class hr_employee(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"
    def _get_sale_order(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        result = {}
        list_o = []
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            for i in order.job_id.sale_ids:
               list_o.append(i.id)
        result[order.id] = list_o
        return result
_columns = {
   'sale_order_ids': fields.function(_get_sale_order, type='many2many', relation="sale.order", string="Sale Orders"),
}

hr_employee()
```

So when you update in the hr.job many2many field then its updated value show in hr.employee object when in job select this job

Another method you can use related

```
'sale_o_ids' : fields.related('job_id', 'sale_ids',
                                       type='many2many',
                                       readonly=True,
                                       relation='sale.order',
                                       string='Available Sale Order'),
```

Hope this thing clear to you

Comment: very Thank you. i used your second choice method. But i got error:-  KeyError: "Field 'job_id' does not exist in object 'browse_record(hr.job, 6)'" . I am writing my code. plz once check thank u for your timing.

Comment: hi, my second code is just an example to explain you how second code work, i added sale_o_ids field in hr.employee so job_id a many2one of hr.job field in hr.employee. For your code you have many2many field hr.applicant, so you have one many2one field in hr.recruitment like **'applicant_id':fields.many2one('hr.applicant', 'Applicant') ** then the related field you can create like: **'sale_o_ids':fields.related('applicant_id', 'crm_lead_ids', type='many2many', readonly=True, relation='crm.lead', string='Crm Leads'),**

Comment: here **crm_lead_ids** in many2many fields exits in hr.applicant hope its clear for you now!!!

Comment: i am very sorry, i used to **'sale_o_ids':fields.related('x_link_to_jobposition', 'x_crm_lead_ids', type='many2many', readonly=True, relation='crm.lead', string='Crm opp')**, in **"hr.applicant"**

Comment: Here i am not understand about **x_crm_lead_ids'**. I create one more many to many fields. but again got same error

Comment: My **'x_link_to_jobposition'** is in **crm.lead**.

Comment: Here i am not understanding about **crm_lead_ids**. i created this fields **x_crm_lead_ids**.  Do i need to create **x_crm_lead_ids**? If not then Which field do i need to use?

Comment: This is my info:-    I created **x_link_to_jobposition** (many2one, Object Relation= hr.job, Model=Lead/Opportunity) in **Lead/Opportunity** Model. I used in **crm.lead**.    Now i want to **display value of this field in hr.applicant**. But i could not complete. Please Sir help me. Thank you

Comment: yes you have to create this **x_crm_lead_ids** field in crm.lead

Comment: can you send your module and what you want to do exactly to my mail at **james.bale.me@gmail.com**